# Detecting object by change of color

Tags: image, detection

I am trying to detect a dart on an image. Here is the image:
[image: Image 1]

I loop over all the x-values on the red line bounded by the two blue lines. And then I try to get the RGB values of every pixel and detect the dart if the background is not white.

However I am unable to find a specific pattern.

The first blue line is located at x=285 and the last one at x=987. The dart is located between x=613 and x=624, here is the obtained data if someone wants to check it:

http://pastebin.com/YVSSVTkL

Any responses would be appreciated on how to detect the dart.

Some side information: I plan to detect on what positon the dart is by getting the position on the x-axis and on the y-axis and then calculating it back to the field it belongs to via the official dimensions of the board.

Regards.

**UPDATE:** Issue has been solved, I was grabbing the data from the wrong image.

Comment: What are the problems you encounter?

Comment: The RGB values that I get do not show any distinctive values once the position of the dart is reached, which is visually definately a current color.

Comment: Are you doing this along the correct y-value?